# Add time/date to Object in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new-ish to PowerShell and am having a problem. I am trying to get a users password last set date and time from a domain and then add 90 days to it. So far I have:

```
$PLS_date = (get-aduser randomuser -Properties PasswordLastSet | Select passwordlastset) | out-string
"Password will expire on $((get-date).adddays(90)($PLS_date))"
```

However this spits out an error:

```
+ "Password will expire on $((get-date).adddays(90)($PLS_date))"
+                                                  ~
Unexpected token '(' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

I have search around to try and find what i am doing wrong but cannot figure it out.

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
$pwdLastSet = Get-ADUser username -Properties PasswordLastSet | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PasswordLastSet
if ( $pwdLastSet ) {
  "Password will expire on: {0}" -f $pwdLastSet.AddDays(90)
}
```